# Search for the lower value in a repetitive pattern in column

Tags: python

I defined a function in Python that get me the lower value after comparing float numbers in a data frame with a particular configuration.
Here is my data frame:

```
xzjSqz_01292    3.2.1.133/0.0001
xzjSqz_01546    3.2.1.52/0.0840
xzjSqz_01559    3.2.1.52/0.0195,2.4.1.25/0.0087
WP_250821872.1  1.2.1.3/0.0032,3.2.1.52/0.0021,1.2.1.28/0.0017
WP_250822533.1  3.2.1.52/0.1338
```

As you can see, some rows in the second column have this pattern (which is okay):

```
3.2.1.133/0.0001
```

But others have this one (which is not okay):

```
3.2.1.52/0.0195,2.4.1.25/0.0087
or 
1.2.1.3/0.0032,3.2.1.52/0.0021,1.2.1.28/0.0017
```

My goal is to check all rows that are not okay, and compare the values after the "/". For example,

```
3.2.1.52/0.0195,2.4.1.25/0.0087
```

I need to compare the values and select the lower one:

```
0.0195 versus 0.0087;
the lower one is 0.0087
```

So, after that, I need to put back that value in the column, but with their respective "code", in this case, is:

```
2.4.1.25
```

So the updated data frame:

```
xzjSqz_01292    3.2.1.133/0.0001
xzjSqz_01546    3.2.1.52/0.0840
xzjSqz_01559    2.4.1.25/0.0087
WP_250821872.1  1.2.1.28/0.0017
WP_250822533.1  3.2.1.52/0.1338
```

In my current code, first takes all the rows where this pattern is present more than one time:
r'(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)/(\d+.\d+)'
and then, I apply the function to get the lower value.
My code:

```
df_input = pd.read_csv(input_file_1, header=None, sep="\t")

# Regular expression to match the pattern you want to exclude
exclude_pattern = r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/(\d+\.\d+)'

# Specify the column where you want to check if the pattern is more than one time
mask = df_input[1].str.count(exclude_pattern) > 1

# Create a new data frame with the filtered data
result_df = df_input[mask]
# print(result_df)

def get_lower_value(row):
    values = re.findall(r'/(\d+\.\d+)', row[1])
    if len(values) >= 2:
        lower_value = min(float(value) for value in values)
        return f"{row[0]} {values[values.index(str(lower_value)) - 1]}/{lower_value}"
    return None

df_input[1] = df_input.apply(get_lower_value, axis=1)
```

However, I got an error:

```
return f"{row[0]} {values[values.index(str(lower_value)) - 1]}/{lower_value}"
ValueError: '0.009' is not in list
```

The error is strange because all the floats have four-digit after the decimal point and in my real data frame there is a lot of 0.009X, where X is any number. However, no 0.009 in my actual data frame, as the error said.

Any idea about what is going on?
Is there any unexpected function behavior?
Is there a better way to reach my goal?

Comment: Why regex when you can use str functions?

Comment: Could you give me an example of your idea? any idea different from mine is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the solution of @Ashenguard, and a little modification in their code, the solution to my issue is here:

```
def get_lower_value(row):
    split = str(row).split(',')
    if len(split) == 1:    # The fine patterns
        return row

    # Find the best in others
    best = None
    value = 0
    for s in split:
        a, b = s.split('/')
        b = float(b.strip())  # Remove leading/trailing whitespace and newline characters
        if best is None or value > b:
            best = s
            value = b

    return best
```

Answer (score 2):

The error you encountered is due to using the index() function on the values list trying to finding the index of a spesefic value (str(lower_value))
that might not exist in the list this why you getting ValueError
A better approach to achieve your goal would be to directly find the minimum value from the values list using min() function and use zip() to to iterate over the values and codes simultaneously his way, you can directly find the corresponding code for the minimum value without worrying about index errors

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df_input = pd.read_csv(input_file_1, header=None, sep="\t")


exclude_pattern = r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/(\d+\.\d+)'

mask = df_input[1].str.count(exclude_pattern) > 1


result_df = df_input[mask]

def get_lower_value(row):
    values_and_codes = re.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/(\d+\.\d+)', row[1])
    if len(values_and_codes) >= 2:
        min_value, min_code = min(values_and_codes, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
        return f"{row[0]} {min_code}/{min_value}"
    return None

df_input[1] = df_input.apply(get_lower_value, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think using str functions is more reliable...

I recommend this function and you can apply it to all of your data without exclude:

```py
def get_lower_value(row):
    split = row[1].split(',')
    if len(split) == 1:    # The fine patterns
        return row

    # Find the best in others
    best = None
    value = 0
    for s in split:
        a, b = s.split('/')
        if best is None or value > float(b)
            best = s
            value = float(b)

    return best
```

---

Let me explain how it works:
Since your data is using `something/float`, one for the correct format and several for others, first we break it into a list(tuple to be exact) of the main pattern.
Then for each pattern, since `something` is not required we break it into `a` and `b` then with a simple minimum finding algorithm on `b` we find the data you want.

Comment: What is your actual output after applying your function?

Comment: when it is in the correct format it will be the same, but when it is multiple like your 3rd row it will the lowest with correct format (`2.4.1.25/0.0087`)

Comment: You did not use ```df_input = pd.read_csv(input_file_1, header=None, sep="\t")``` before, did you? Because, based on your approach I got the following error:
```AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'. Did you mean: 'plot'?```

Comment: No, I haven't but I assumed it was string... Then just use `str(row).split(',')` or based on your own code `row[1].split(',')`

Comment: Your approach is closer than mine (to my expected output). However, I got a different error. I'm going to understand that error before make more questions.

Comment: In my real data frame (the big one), the first line is: ```bbKfHd_00391 3.2.1.52/0.3729```. Based on that, the new error is this:```ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.3729\nName: 0'``` I think this is weird, because there is not any symbols there. However, maybe is for the period in the float

Comment: Which one did you use? `str(row).split(',')` or `row[1].split(',')`

Comment: the first one:```str(row).split(',')```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254641/discussion-between-ashenguard-and-mauri1313).

Answer (score 0):

A vectorized way to do this, using `.str` methods as mentioned in comments:

```
# assuming second column name is 'B'
df = df \
    .assign(B=df['B'].str.split(',')) \
    .explode('B') \
    .sort_values('B', key=lambda s: s.str.rsplit('/', n=1).str[-1])
df.groupby(df.index).first()
```

Explained:

```
.assign(B=df['B'].str.split(','))
```

first, split into groups. Now this column contains a list of addresses (or whatever it is) instead of a comma-separated string

```
.explode('B')
```

split every row into a number of records. So, a row with two addresses will become two rows, with only one address each

```
.sort_values('B', key=lambda s: s.str.rsplit('/', n=1).str[-1])
```

sort by the second part of address (whatever comes after slash)

```
df.groupby(df.index).first()
```

take the first, smallest, record for each of the original rows.

Answer (score 0):

Using split and max() with a key, should work without regular expressions:

For example:

```
S = "1.2.1.3/0.0032,3.2.1.52/0.0021,1.2.1.28/0.0017"

smallest = min(S.split(','),key=lambda x:float(x.split('/')[-1]))

print(smallest)

1.2.1.28/0.0017
```